# Is Raspbian signal(2) handling persistent or non-persistent?

Tags: raspbian, c, pigpio

I've been looking at the signal handling in a library I am using in a project of my own {Joan's **pigpio** as it happens} but having read the Raspbian man pages for `signal(7)`, `sigaction(2)` and finally `signal(2)`, I am trying to determine what happens if a custom signal handler is installed and the process receives a signal of the specified type.  Under the following heading of the `signal(2)` manpage is:

> ### Portability
>
> The only portable use of `signal()` is to set a signal's disposition to `SIG_DFL` or `SIG_IGN`. The semantics when using `signal()` to establish a signal handler vary across systems (and POSIX.1 explicitly permits this variation); do not use it for this purpose.
>   POSIX.1 solved the portability mess by specifying `sigaction(2)`, which provides explicit control of the semantics when a signal handler is invoked; use that interface instead of `signal()`.
>   In the original UNIX systems, when a handler that was established using `signal()` was invoked by the delivery of a signal, the disposition of the signal would be reset to `SIG_DFL`, and the system did not block delivery of further instances of the signal. This is equivalent to calling `sigaction(2)` with the following flags:
>
> `sa.sa_flags = SA_RESETHAND | SA_NODEFER;`
>
> System V also provides these semantics for `signal()`. This was bad because the signal might be delivered again before the handler had a chance to reestablish itself. Furthermore, rapid deliveries of the same signal could result in recursive invocations of the handler.
>
> BSD improved on this situation, but unfortunately also changed the semantics of the existing `signal()` interface while doing so. On BSD, when a signal handler is invoked, the signal disposition is not reset, and further instances of the signal are blocked from being delivered while the handler is executing.  Furthermore, certain blocking system calls are automatically restarted if interrupted by a signal handler (see `signal(7)`). The BSD semantics are equivalent to calling `sigaction(2)` with the following flags:
>
> `sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;`
>
> The situation on Linux is as follows:
>
> - The kernel's `signal()` system call provides System V semantics.
> - By default, in `glibc` 2 and later, the `signal()` wrapper function does not invoke the kernel system call. Instead, it calls `sigaction(2)` using flags that supply BSD semantics. This default behavior is provided as long as the `_BSD_SOURCE` feature test macro is defined. By default, `_BSD_SOURCE` is defined; it is also implicitly defined if one defines `_GNU_SOURCE`, and can of course be explicitly defined.
> - On glibc 2 and later, if the `_BSD_SOURCE` feature test macro is not defined, then signal() provides System V semantics. (The default implicit definition of `_BSD_SOURCE` is not provided if one invokes `gcc(1)` in one of its standard modes (`-std=xxx` or `-ansi`) or defines various other feature test macros such as `_POSIX_SOURCE`, `_XOPEN_SOURCE`, or `_SVID_SOURCE`; see `feature_test_macros(7)`.)

Given that *persistent* signal handlers are those on systems where a handler is **NOT** reset to `SIG_DFL` on receipt of that signal (and *non-persistent* ones are those that are):

***Are the handlers persistent on RPis?***

Does it depend on those *feature test macros* when the library and/or my project is (re)compiled OR, perhaps, what they were when the *kernel* was compiled?

Answer (score 2):

As flakeshake pointed out and then deleted for some reason, this is only an issue *if you intentionally want to do things the **wrong way**.* All of the documents you refer to make it very clear the point here is *don't use `signal()`*.  It exists because it's part of ANSI/ISO C, i.e., it has to for compatibility with ancient code.  To be blunt: If it is too hard for you to just use `sigaction()`, then how is it possible for you to care about the semantics of what you are doing (the wrong way, on purpose)?

Anyhow, this is easy enough to demonstrate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void handler (int s __attribute__((unused))) {
    write(2, "Hello world.\n", 13);
}

int main (void) 
{
    printf("PID %d\n", (int)getpid());
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler);
    while(1) sleep(1);
    puts("Goodbye!");
    return 1;
}
```

Unhandled signals mostly terminate a process.  Hopefully what that code does is extremely clear.<sup>1</sup>  So let's compile it using no switches:

```
 gcc test.c
```

Run it, then from somewhere else, repeatedly `kill -s SIGUSR1 [whatever pid]`.  You get:

```
Hello world.
Hello world.
```

Over and over.  Now compile it `gcc --std=c89 test.c` and do the same thing.  You get:

```
Hello world.
“./a.out” terminated by signal SIGUSR1 (User defined signal 1)
```

As stated, the handler was reset because you told the compiler that's the behavior you want.

> Does it depend on those feature test macros when the library and/or my project is (re)compiled OR, perhaps, what they were when the kernel was compiled?

Well, it's implied that _BSD_SOURCE is *effectively* set/used by default (in the library).  Linux unofficially aims for POSIX compliance, which doesn't help here much because [POSIX just says the behaviour on this is implementation defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html), probably because POSIX does include `sigaction()`, which is what you are explicitly *supposed* to be using if you are concerned about standards, the predictable behavior defined in standards (and redefined and refined in later standards such as POSIX), etc.  If not, then who cares.  Use the wrong function and leave it up to the implementation.

Sort of interestingly, trying to undefine `_BSD_SOURCE`:

```
#undef _BSD_SOURCE
```

Does not result in the non-persistent handlers that `--std=c89` does.  Of course, it doesn't say anywhere that it would, it just refers to the "default implicit definition" of _BSD_SOURCE used by GCC/glibc.

Generally speaking "feature test macros" that invoke *non-default* behaviour work if you *define* them for a specific compilation unit.

---

<sup>1. As SlySven points out, using `fprintf` in a signal handler is not a good practice; see the list of *"Async-signal-safe functions"* in `man 7 signal` about this.  Using magic number 2 instead of `fileno(stderr)` is not a great practice either, but since `fileno()` isn't async safe here it better demonstrates the principle.  See comments below for more discussion.</sup>

Comment: I was wondering whether the behaviour is set (possibly by the feature macro) when the ***kernel*** is compiled though? Of course I am recompiling the library, and of course I/joan are using `sigaction()` rather than `signal()`, it is just the documentation for the latter is pertinent...!

Comment: Oh and for the record your test case is violating another thing in that it is using a `printf()` family function in the handler which I do not think is safe because it indirectly allocates memory off the heap - which is not something that can be done atomically...!

Comment: Well, `valgrind` doesn't seem to think there's anything wrong with it -- although if that weren't *a compiled in constant* I guess you could play games to see what the state of some global string turns out to be at the time.

Comment: I actually stumbled across a site which included a section on [signals](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3903) which is very informative about all sorts of good (and bad) C/POSIX coding practices and explains why they are so. The issue with the example comes under heading [SIG30-C](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers)!

Comment: Point taken!  TBH I don't use them for anything except ignoring things.  Actually there is a long list of "Async-signal-safe functions" in `man 7 signal` but predictably they don't include much in the way of I/O -- except for `write()` and `read()`, so there is a "safe and compliant version of this" (maybe I'll edit in a reference to these comments).  You can also `fork()`/`exec()`, so you could use a handler to do a hard reset, etc.

Comment: Okay, voila, compliant version.  5 points if you can spot the cardinal rule this one breaks though.

Comment: Just possibly, from `puts(3)` manpage: "**BUGS** It is not advisable to mix calls to output functions from the `stdio` library with low-level calls to `write(2)` for the file descriptor associated with the same output stream; the results will be undefined and very probably not what you want." Mind you, you *are* using `stderr` for the output from the handler and `stdout` for the output from main so that might be okay - OTOH at the terminal those streams will normally be mixed - and we know from the GhostBusters ["Don't cross the streams"](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Ghostbusters)...!